# Better way to write this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda expression that looks at an array of objects ('fields') that may or may not have specific items in it.  I would like to retrieve values if they exist; if no field in the array has a code of 'SomeCode', then there is no value to retrieve.  I'm curious if there is a cleaner way to write the below, since I'll need to do this for a lot of fields and done want to run through the 'FirstOrDefault' call twice.

```
if (fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == "SomeCode") != null) 
{
    obj.CodeValue = fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == "SomeCode").Value;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for any insight on doing this in a 'Lambda only' fashion; I'd like to improve my skills in this area and figured that there would be something cleaner than either calling it twice or simply assigning it to an interim object.

Comment: Do you want to set `obj.CodeValue` at all if there are no matches? Would it be *harmful* to do so?

Comment: if you're only expecting one value, it may also make sense to use `SingleOrDefault`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - It may be (harmful) if the value ends up being nullable.  Thanks, Brad - Good call; thanks, since I am expecting at most only one value.

Answer (score 5):

Just cache the return value from `FirstOrDefault` and then compare it.

```
var item = fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == "SomeCode");
if (item != null) 
{
    obj.CodeValue = item.Value;
}
```

In your current code you are querying twice, once for checking `null`, later to access value.

Comment: I'm doing this now; I thought that there might be a 'lambda-only solution.  Thanks, though.

Comment: @EvConrad, I am not sure What you mean by "Lamda-only" solution, but in your current code you are querying twice, the code in answer will query once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var field = fields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == "SomeCode");

if (field != null) 
    obj.CodeValue = field.Value;
```